# How can i target an individual item in a titanium alloy listview?

Tags: listview, titanium-alloy

in titanium-alloy, how can i target specifically the first item in a titanium listview (i need to change the background color of only the first item)?

VIEW with listview:

```
<ListView id="hm_channel_comments" defaultItemTemplate="hm_commentTemplate">
<ListSection name="hm_comments" id="hm_comments_section"/>
```

some things ive tried (always returns "undefined"):

```
$.hm_channel_comments.Item[0].setBackgroundColor("blue"); //not working
$.hm_comments_section.itemIndex[0].setBackgroundColor("blue"); //not working
console.log($.hm_comments_section.itemIndex[0] + " $.hm_comments_section.itemIndex[0] "); not working
console.log($.hm_comments_section.item[0] + " $.hm_comments_section.item[0] ");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one needs to (a) get the listItemObject of specific listsection and (b) update it. something like this (when you only want to change the backgroundColor to navy of the first item of the listSection):

groups.xml contains a listsection with the id "myTeamSectionJoined".

groups.js:

```
function disableOwnBuddyTransfer(){
    var groupFounder = $.myTeamSectionJoined.getItemAt(0);
    console.log("groupFounder" + JSON.stringify(groupFounder));
    groupFounder.d_four.backgroundColor = "navy";
    $.myTeamSectionJoined.updateItemAt(0, groupFounder);
}
```

really useful info is at http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_ListView_Guide